# How to scroll a “postion: fixed” div element , only inside a particular div content on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Let's say I have the following HTML and CSS and jQuery:

```js
$("#blue_square").css("top", $(window).height() / 2 - 80)
```

```css
.divTwo {
  position: relative;
}

#blue_square {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 370px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divOne"></div>

<div class="divTwo">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-10">
    <div id="blue_square" style="top: 310px;">Blue</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="divThree"></div>
```

The problem I am noticing is that the `blue_square` div element, is somehow showing up on `divOne` but I was only expecting it to start from `divTwo`.

My question is, how do I make `blue_square` to start inside `divtwo` and have it contained  with in the `divtwo` while I scroll its content?

I only want to see position blue_square position: fixed element inside `divTwo` and that's it. I don't want to see it on `divOne` or `divThree` when I am scrolling their content. How can I achieve this with JavaScript?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please change it to make it a [mcve]

Comment: Please post a working example where we can see the problem in action.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the css from fixed to absolute css and it will work according to your requirement:-

```
.divTwo {
        position: relative;
        overflow: auto; /* Hide the overflow to prevent scrollbars on .divTwo */
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
    }
    #blue_square {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 9;
        width: 370px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 6px transparent;
        height: 100%; /* Set the height to 100% to fill .divTwo */
        left: 0;
        word-break: break-word;
    }
```

Comment: No, if i do that then I can’t see the blue square when I am scrolling div two content. I need position fixed

Comment: Sorry for being late but if that's your case then you can find solution above which was shared by @Gabriele. I think that will work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific use case you could use `position:sticky` but if you want to position it based on the `right` you will have to use some creative calculation with `calc` and apply it to the `left` (*since the left/right/top/bottom are offsets from its initial position*)

```js
$("#blue_square").css("top", $(window).height() / 2 - 80)
```

```css
body>div[class] {
  max-height: 250px;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  overflow: auto;
}

.divTwo {
  position: relative;
  max-height:150px;
}

#blue_square {
  position: sticky;
  left: calc(100% - 100px);
  z-index: 9;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #000;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="divOne">
  Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque tempus tellus dui, sed convallis leo molestie sit amet. Morbi tempus commodo turpis. Sed vulputate, magna ut convallis finibus, urna sapien cursus
  mauris, sit amet scelerisque ex diam sagittis turpis. Cras et nunc est. Aenean at metus et magna scelerisque consequat ut id felis. Donec quis diam sit amet justo egestas congue in non ante. Vestibulum gravida bibendum nibh. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce
  sed felis id nunc luctus suscipit. Praesent leo diam, auctor ac posuere eget, efficitur egestas sem. Mauris vel sapien eget justo tempus elementum lobortis lobortis felis. Phasellus eget dolor mauris. Morbi tincidunt pharetra mauris eu convallis. Duis
  nec dolor scelerisque nulla faucibus cursus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. </div>

<div class="divTwo">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-10">
    <div id="blue_square" style="top: 310px;">Blue</div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eu laoreet dui. Vestibulum rhoncus tortor eu metus molestie tristique. Praesent tempus lorem eget dignissim bibendum. Suspendisse lacinia sit amet elit ut eleifend. Sed fringilla dolor
    id interdum varius. Nulla in tortor rutrum, pellentesque nibh a, cursus nulla. Fusce nibh ex, faucibus sit amet imperdiet ut, mattis non augue. Nullam lobortis nunc felis, quis lobortis ante vulputate at. Vivamus ac est quis purus lobortis elementum. Sed fringilla dolor
    id interdum varius. Nulla in tortor rutrum, pellentesque nibh a, cursus nulla. Fusce nibh ex, faucibus sit amet imperdiet ut, mattis non augue. Nullam lobortis nunc felis, quis lobortis ante vulputate at. Vivamus ac est quis purus lobortis elementum.
  </div>

</div>

<div class="divThree">
Suspendisse lacinia sit amet elit ut eleifend. Sed fringilla dolor
  id interdum varius. Nulla in tortor rutrum, pellentesque nibh a, cursus nulla. Fusce nibh ex, faucibus sit amet imperdiet ut, mattis non augue. Nullam lobortis nunc felis, quis lobortis ante vulputate at. Vivamus ac est quis purus lobortis elementum.</div>
```

---

A more robust solution would be to use `position:relative` on the `#blue_square` and `position:relative` on its container, and then use another element for the scrolling content. So it would require some changes to the html/css structure

(*something like the following*)

```js
$("#blue_square").css("top", $(window).height() / 2 - 80)
```

```css
.divOne,.divTwo,.divThree {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  overflow: auto;
}

.divTwo {
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.scrolling-content{
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}

#blue_square {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #000;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="divOne">
  Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque tempus tellus dui, sed convallis leo molestie sit amet. Morbi tempus commodo turpis. Sed vulputate, magna ut convallis finibus, urna sapien cursus
  mauris, sit amet scelerisque ex diam sagittis turpis. Cras et nunc est. Aenean at metus et magna scelerisque consequat ut id felis. Donec quis diam sit amet justo egestas congue in non ante. Vestibulum gravida bibendum nibh. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce
  sed felis id nunc luctus suscipit. Praesent leo diam, auctor ac posuere eget, efficitur egestas sem. Mauris vel sapien eget justo tempus elementum lobortis lobortis felis. Phasellus eget dolor mauris. Morbi tincidunt pharetra mauris eu convallis. Duis
  nec dolor scelerisque nulla faucibus cursus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. </div>

<div class="divTwo">
    <div id="blue_square" style="top: 110px;">Blue</div>
  <div class="scrolling-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eu laoreet dui. Vestibulum rhoncus tortor eu metus molestie tristique. Praesent tempus lorem eget dignissim bibendum. Suspendisse lacinia sit amet elit ut eleifend. Sed fringilla dolor
    id interdum varius. Nulla in tortor rutrum, pellentesque nibh a, cursus nulla. Fusce nibh ex, faucibus sit amet imperdiet ut, mattis non augue. Nullam lobortis nunc felis, quis lobortis ante vulputate at. Vivamus ac est quis purus lobortis elementum. Sed fringilla dolor
    id interdum varius. Nulla in tortor rutrum, pellentesque nibh a, cursus nulla. Fusce nibh ex, faucibus sit amet imperdiet ut, mattis non augue. Nullam lobortis nunc felis, quis lobortis ante vulputate at. Vivamus ac est quis purus lobortis elementum.
  </div>

</div>

<div class="divThree">
Suspendisse lacinia sit amet elit ut eleifend. Sed fringilla dolor
  id interdum varius. Nulla in tortor rutrum, pellentesque nibh a, cursus nulla. Fusce nibh ex, faucibus sit amet imperdiet ut, mattis non augue. Nullam lobortis nunc felis, quis lobortis ante vulputate at. Vivamus ac est quis purus lobortis elementum.</div>
```